# Deleting a detached database SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I detached a database, and when i try to re-attach it i am getting error:

> CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\RoadMap.mdf'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5123)

Is there a way i can delete that database and create new one instead of re-attaching it.

Comment: Is there an error that is not allowing you to create a new database?

Comment: CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\RoadMap.mdf'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5123)

Comment: there is an error not letting me attach DB. and i can not create new one because the old one still exits

Comment: any chance you might *not* be admin on that box, and therefore, the re-attach fails since it cannot access the file? Are the paths correct for your setup? System Error 5 is "Access denied"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just had to delete the database logs from the defualt location and i was able to create new database.

Thanks